# 2 independent left join queries won't work together

Tags: sql, left-join, sqlplus

Ultimately I want my output to be a pivot query similar to below which I am comfortable doing

e.g.

```
      Date CO  RU ER AB

    1/1/18  5  20  0  0
    
    2/1/18  0   5  0  0
    
    3/1/18  0   0  0  0
    
    4/1/18  1   0  0  0
```

However, to get to that point I want to fill my data set with zero where no data exists

The table holds data similar to the following

```
Date/time Process_type Status

1/1/18 10:05 150 RU
2/1/18 14:00 150 CO
4/1/18 18:00 100 ER
```

On any given day there could be no processes.

I have written 2 queries whose purpose was to fill the gaps in the data. ie. fill days and statuses with zero counts where that combination does not exist.

1. This is a date range query that ensures zeroes are returned if the count is zero for dates where there is no info. This would give something similar to below

   ```
   Date     Count

   1/1/18    25
   2/1/18     5
   3/1/18     0
   4/1/18     1
   ```
2. This is a status query that ensures zeroes are returned if that zero is not status is not present

   ```
   status count

   AB 0
   RU 2
   CO 25
   ER 0
   ```

I want to join the 2 queries so that I will get zeroes for both dates and status if the count is zero.

```
Date Status Count

1/1/18 AB 0
1/1/18 CO 0
1/1/18 ER 0
1/1/18 RU 0
2/1/18 AB 0
2/1/18 CO 6
3/1/18 ER 0
4/1/18 RU 1
```

When I join them up in Query 3 it wont run and gets the following error. I have tried a few different ways with no joy.

> Error report -
>
> SQL Error: ORA-00904: "TD"."TMP_DATE": invalid identifier
>
> 904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Query 1

```
-- 
-- Working out dates with nulls if zero count
--
with tmp_dates as (
    select trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 as tmp_date
    from dual
    connect by level <= 5
)
select
    count(pi.crtd_tstmp),
    td.tmp_date
from 
    tmp_dates td
    left join procedure_instance pi 
        on (td.tmp_date = trunc(pi.crtd_tstmp) and proc_oid = 150)
group by 
    td.tmp_date
order by 
    tmp_date;
```

Query 2

```
--
-- Working with Categories with zero if no category
--
with status_table as (
    select 'CO' as instanceid from dual union
    select 'RU' as instanceid from dual union
    select 'ER' as instanceid from dual union
    select 'AB' as instanceid from dual
)
select
    count(pi.crtd_tstmp),
    st.instanceid
from 
    status_table st
    left join procedure_instance pi
        on (st.instanceid = pi.stat and proc_oid = 150)
group by 
    st.instanceid
order by
    st.instanceid;
```

Query 3

```
--
-- join together
--
with tmp_dates as (
    select trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 as tmp_date
    from dual
    connect by level <= 5
),
status_table as (
    select 'CO' as instanceid from dual union
    select 'RU' as instanceid from dual union
    select 'ER' as instanceid from dual union
    select 'AB' as instanceid from dual
)
select
    count(pi.crtd_tstmp),
    td.tmp_date,
    st.instanceid
from 
    tmp_dates td,
    status_table st
    left join procedure_instance pi 
        on (td.tmp_date = trunc(pi.crtd_tstmp) and proc_oid = 150)
    left join procedure_instance pi 
        on (st.instanceid = pi.stat and proc_oid = 150)
group by 
    td.tmp_date,
    st.instanceid
order by 
    tmp_date;
```

Comment: Comma means cross join but has lower precedence than keyword ("explicit") JOINs. So the left joins are done first & alias td is not known there. This is why you should not mix comma with keyword joins.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL LEFT JOIN error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2668926/3404097)

Comment: What did you learn googling your error message with & without your names/strings? Also: Per debugging basics & in pursuit of a [mcve] you could have chopped code out until you had minimal code with the error, more or less `select td.tmp_date from tmp_dates td, status_table st left join procedure_instance pi 
on td.tmp_date = '...')`. Then reread the manual re joins. And googled re your error message & left join with comma (which is all that is left) & 'site:stackoverflow.com'.

Comment: Am struggling with this being a duplicate and the question given a negative raing  I have researched the error code and can't work out how is applies as it only happens when I add the second join.  when I comment out the second join it works fine.

Comment: My first comment explains the problem and I gave you a link that explains the problem. `T t, U u JOIN ...` means `T t , (U u JOIN ...)` not `(T t, U u) JOIN ...` so `t` is not known in `...`. Add parentheses or replace `,` by `CROSS JOIN` because that gives `T t CROSS JOIN U u JOIN ...` which means `(T t CROSS JOIN U u) JOIN ...` like you want. If I have `x+y` and `v` and "add" `*` to get `x+y*v` it is `x+(y*z)` not `(x+y)*z` PS What do you think my first comment & the duplicate are trying to say? What is the first thing that you don't understand in them?

Comment: To find your problem you might need to read a lot of hits from googling 'site:stackoverflow.com SQL Error: ORA-00904 invalid identifier'. But fewer googling also with 'join (comma OR ",")' after you minimize code, but maybe still many--but my first hit answers your question. Because I would expect your problem to be hard for you characterize clearly & find, I wouldn't downvote for lack of searching. But since this is a code question it can be downvoted & closed for not having a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code in it. (Preferably also a link to sqlfiddle.com where you cut & pasted & ran it.)

Comment: Although your query 3 has a compilation problem with comma, why are you even using comma when you combine your queries 1 &2??

Comment: You don't clearly explain what you want the result to be. You just say vague things like " join the 2 queries so that I will get zeroes for both dates and status if the count is zero". Explain what rows go in the result as a function of what rows are in the input or in the 2 queries.

Comment: ok have re-read the comments and now undertand and have a working solution.  Thanks for your comments and patience.

Comment: @philipxy actually it runs but I think is doing a cross join. For the days where everything is zero it is correct  for other days the numbers are way out

Comment: @philipxy I have done in a different way.  I removed the second join and did the substitution and work within the Pivot

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer, not as part of your question. (You can accept it after the minimum wait time.) You can edit then undelete your deleted answer. For your question you can click on 'edited' then on the 'roll back' of the last version. If you edit your question to be clear then you may get upvotes & not downvotes.

Comment: @philipxy updated as you described.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to get round this a different way, I used the pivot to fill the process statutes instead of using query 2 and the second join.  Works exactly as wanted now.

```
select Process_created, 
    nvl(Complete, 0) as Complete,
    nvl(Error, 0) as Error,
    nvl(Running, 0) as Running,
    nvl(Abort, 0) as Abort
       from(
with tmp_dates as (
    select trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 as tmp_date
    from dual
    connect by level <= 30
)
select
    count(pi.crtd_tstmp) as number_of,
    td.tmp_date as Process_created,
    pi.stat as status
from 
    tmp_dates td
    left join procedure_instance pi 
        on (td.tmp_date = trunc(pi.crtd_tstmp) and proc_oid = 150)
group by 
    td.tmp_date,pi.stat
order by 
    tmp_date)src
    pivot(
sum(number_of)
for status in ('CO' as Complete, 'ER' as Error, 'RU' as Running, 'AB' as Abort )) piv order by process_created;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this with only one table in the from clause?

```
with tmp_dates as (
    select trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 as tmp_date
    from dual
    connect by level <= 5
),status_table as (select 'CO' as instanceid from dual union
select 'RU' as instanceid from dual union
select 'ER' as instanceid from dual union
select 'AB' as instanceid from dual)
select count(pi.crtd_tstmp), td.tmp_date, st.instanceid
from tmp_dates td
left join procedure_instance pi on (td.tmp_date = trunc(pi.crtd_tstmp) and proc_oid = 150)
right join status_table st on (st.instanceid = pi.stat and proc_oid = 150)
group by td.tmp_date,st.instanceid
order by tmp_date;
```

Comment: gets an error  Error at Command Line : 11 Column : 11
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Is there no table named procedure_instance?

Comment: sorry, yes I had changed a couple of table names.  so that now runs but does not give the overall correct solution of each date and each status

Comment: If the procedure_instance table is empty what would you expect the query to return? In other words, what would the correct result look like if procedure_instance had no rows?

Answer (score -1):

Try this and let me know what errors you get

```
--
-- join together
--
WITH tmp_dates
AS (
    SELECT trunc(sysdate) - LEVEL + 1 AS tmp_date
    FROM dual connect BY LEVEL <= 5
    )
    ,status_table
AS (
    SELECT 'CO' AS instanceid FROM dual

    UNION

    SELECT 'RU' AS instanceid FROM dual

    UNION

    SELECT 'ER' AS instanceid FROM dual

    UNION

    SELECT 'AB' AS instanceid FROM dual
    )
SELECT count(pi.crtd_tstmp)
    ,td.tmp_date
    ,st.instanceid
FROM tmp_dates td
    ,status_table st
LEFT JOIN procedure_instance pi ON (
        td.tmp_date = trunc(pi.crtd_tstmp)
        AND proc_oid = 150
        )
LEFT JOIN procedure_instance pi2 ON (
        st.instanceid = pi2.stat
        AND proc_oid = 150
        )
GROUP BY td.tmp_date
    ,st.instanceid
ORDER BY td.tmp_date;
```

Comment: streetORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 31 Column: 11 @vic

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer to the question? If so please explain why. If not please comment instead.