# Joining 4 tables in mySQL and including NULL values

Tags: mysql, select, outer-join

I am trying to list all customers’ names with each product that customer has ordered and include customers who don't have an order. Also If a customer has ordered the same product multiple times, only list the product once for that customer.

I have the beginning of the query set up so its showing all customers and each product ordered but I can't seem to figure out how to add customers with NULL value ( meaning they haven't ordered an item.) I know left outer join is supposed to be used somehow. This is what I have so far:

```
select distinct
c.customerName, p.productName
from
products p, customers c, orders o, orderDetails d
left join
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see your table structure and an example of your desired results.

Comment: Does that look like any `left join` example you have ever seen in a reference? PS Reading the reference re `,` & `join`, you will see that comma does cross join but has lower precedence. So `join` joins are done first. Don't use `, ` & `join` in the same `from`. PS In code questions give a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL LEFT JOIN error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668806/mysql-left-join-error)

Answer (score 0):

When using a `left join` a syntax like:

```
select distinct
c.customerName, p.productName
from customers c
left join order o on c.id = o.customer_id
left join orderDetails d on o.id = d.order_id
left join products p on p.id = d.product_id AND
          p.productName = 'cow'
```